# how can include the delimiter pattern in preg_split?

Tags: php

Ok, I am trying to capture a specific date time format and split a long string into arrays. the string is a chat log I want to make it an array of messages with each date time of lines as the array key and the rest of the message as the array index contents. each message may contain line break in it so what it should keep the line break and adds it to array, this is what i came up with to split it. but it will remove the search delimiter and I dont whant to do that.

the data string is like this:

```
5/5/18, 11:48 AM - +[somePhoneNumberHere] created group "someChatNAme"
5/5/18, 11:48 AM - You were added
2/6/19, 8:22 AM - +[somePhoneNumberHere] : <Media omitted>
2/6/19, 8:41 AM - +[somePhoneNumberHere]: 
2/6/19, 8:45 AM - +[somePhoneNumberHere]: some multi line text
some multi line text
some multi line text
2/6/19, 9:27 AM - +[somePhoneNumberHere]: ☘
```

so the pattern to split it is a line break char followed by a date.
i noticed that line break `ascii` code is 10 so i did not know which character it is so I used `chr(10)` to replicate it.

```
$file = preg_split('/\\'.chr(10).'((\d{2}|\d{1})\/(\d{2}|\d{1})\/(\d{2}|\d{1}), (\d{2}|\d{1}):(\d{2}|\d{1}) (AM|PM) - )/', $string,null,PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);

print_r($file);
```

what I want to get is: something like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 5/5/18, 11:48 AM - +[somePhoneNumberHere] created group "‬‎someChatNAme"
    [1] => 5/5/18, 11:48 AM - You were added
    [2] => 2/6/19, 8:22 AM - +[somePhoneNumberHere]: 
    [3] => 2/6/19, 8:41 AM - +[somePhoneNumberHere]: 
    [4] => 2/6/19, 8:45 AM - +[somePhoneNumberHere]: some multi line text
some multi line text
some multi line text
    [5] => 2/6/19, 9:27 AM - +[somePhoneNumberHere]: ☘
)
```

but what I get from this code is something like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 5/5/18, 11:48 AM - +[somePhoneNumberHere] created group "someChatName‬‎"
    [1] => 5/5/18, 11:48 AM - 
    [2] => 5
    [3] => 5
    [4] => 18
    [5] => 11
    [6] => 48
    [7] => AM
    [8] => You were added
    [9] => 2/6/19, 8:22 AM - 
    [10] => 2
    [11] => 6
    [12] => 19
    [13] => 8
    [14] => 22
    [15] => AM
    [16] => +[somePhoneNumberHere]: 
    [17] => 2/6/19, 8:41 AM - 
    [18] => 2
    [19] => 6
    [20] => 19
    [21] => 8
    [22] => 41
    [23] => AM
    [24] => +[somePhoneNumberHere]: 
    [25] => 2/6/19, 9:27 AM - 
    [26] => 2
    [27] => 6
    [28] => 19
    [29] => 9
    [30] => 27
    [31] => AM
    [32] => 2/6/19, 8:45 AM - 
    [33] => 2
    [34] => 6
    [35] => 19
    [36] => 8
    [37] => 41
    [38] => AM
    [39] => +[somePhoneNumberHere]: some multi line text
some multi line text
some multi line text
    [40] => +[somePhoneNumberHere]: ☘
```

whats wrong with this?

as you can see only the first row of the result array is like what I wanted and the date and time is separated and added to individual index which I don want it to be like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$file = preg_split('/\R(?=(\d{1,2}\/){2}\d{1,2}, \d{1,2}:\d{1,2} (A|P)M - )/', $string);
```

Comment: another thing, if the first number was 4 digits can you tell me what should ?=(\d{1,2}) change into?

Comment: @mfrHoujat Assuming your date is `YYYY/MM/DD` and the month and days can be either 1 or 2 digits, you need to change this part `(\d{1,2}\/){2}` to `\d{4}\/\d{1,2}\/`